# NServiceBus handler set named dependency with Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, nservicebus

For an NServiceBus handler I want to specify a named dependency. I am using castle windsor as my IOC container. By default NServiceBus registers all handlers with the container so when I try to also set registrations it throws an error on startup.....

"Component EventMessageHandler could not be registered. There is already a component with that name. Did you want to modify the existing component instead? If not, make sure you specify a unique name.".

Is there a way to override this to specify the named dependency. So have a registration like this...

```
container.Register(
Component.For<IService>()
    .ImplementedBy<Service>()
    .Named("default")
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<Config>(config1)));

container.Register(
Component.For<IHandleMessages<EventMessage>>().ImplementedBy<EventMessageHandler>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IService), "default")));
```

For a handler that looks like this....

```
public class EventMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<EventMessage>
{
    private IService service;

public EventMessageHandler(IService service)
{
    this.service = service;
}

public void Handle(EventMessage message)
{
    service.DoStuff();
}
}
```

This is because I have multiple implementations of the IService so want to be able to specify specific ones for specific handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it by creating a container, preregister everything and then hand it over to the BusConfiguration (assuming you're on NSB v5.0 or greater).

Here's the code:

```
BusConfiguration busConfiguration = new BusConfiguration();
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyServiceImpl1>().Named("s1"));
container.Register(Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<MyServiceImpl2>().Named("s2"));
container.Register(Component.For<MyMessageHandler>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IMyService), "s1")));

busConfiguration.UseContainer<WindsorBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(container));
```

Now on your handler, if you have a dependency to your service, it will be the one you've specified:

```
public class MyMessageHandler : IHandleMessages<MyMessage>
{
    public MyMessageHandler(IMyService service)
    {
       //service is of the type you specified in your config
    }

    public void Handle(MyMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message arrived");
    }
}
```

One thing to note, you'd have to do your registration exactly as shown above. If you try to do it this way it will blow up:

```
//Wouldn't work
container.Register(Component.For<IHandleMessages<MyMessage>>().ImplementedBy<MyMessageHandler>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IMyService), "s2")));
```

Having said all that, why is it bad to inject the actual class and not the interface to achieve the same thing?

Comment: How do I wire the container and busConfiguration together?

Comment: thanks for the response. the bit I had wrong was the registration for the handler. container.Register(Component.For<MyMessageHandler>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IMyService), "s1")));
being correct  whereas container.Register(Component.For<IHandleMessages<MyMessage>>().ImplementedBy<MyMessageHandler>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IMyService), "s2"))); was blowing up. Not sure what you mean by "why is it bad to inject the actual class and not the interface to achieve the same thing?".....The example of gave was a simplified version of my actual code.

Comment: @JohnG Glad it is resolved. What I meant was, if you have two different implementation of a service / interface and one handler specifically requires one implementation to operate, why not inject that concrete class (instead of interface) and make the dependency more 'pronounced' rather than hiding that dependency in a IoC container configuration using a named dependency?